# How to fix SignalR "Failed connection handshake" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

SignalR sometime throws exception (approximately 4 exceptions/week) "Failed connection handshake".
I think reason could be unstable internet connection on client but I'm not sure (other reason could be wrong configuration or implementation). Has anyone the same problem? And should I solve it when most of the time it is ok?
It is MVC .Net Core app.

Here is log:

```
{"EventId":{"Id":5,"Name":"HandshakeFailed"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext","TransportConnectionId":"rC64r0HCfzSQCqE7OB5h-A","RequestId":"0HLNJ4TCNIKN8:00000002","RequestPath":"/hub/status","CorrelationId":null,"ConnectionId":"0HLNJ4TCNIKN8"}
```

Comment: Is there any significant impact of this being thrown?

Comment: In this app SignalR refreshes "badge" which shows count of new messages. When this exception occurs, the badges are not refreshed until the user refreshes page. But if the reason is wrong internet connection on the client side it should not be a problem.

Comment: Old question, but in case anyone has the same issue, there's a known issue with .Net Core 2.1 that is apparently fixed in 2.2 - https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/3169